# How to link to previous/next entries in a section?

Tags: pagination, navigation, entrymodel

What would be the equivalent in Craft of ExpressionEngine's [Next/Previous entry linking](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_linking.html)? I was looking at `getNext()` and `getPrev()` (and their aliases `next` and `prev`) (via the [EntryModel docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel)), but when I try the obvious:

```
<a href="{{ entry.prev.url }}">Previously: {{ entry.prev.title }}</a>
```

I just get the current entry's data.

What piece am I missing here?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You are probably not using this within a craft.entries loop. Position it inside a loop or set custom parameters for your prev and next elements:

```
{# Set parameters for prev/next elements list #}
{% set params = craft.entries.section('blog').order('title asc') %}

{# Get the prev/next elements #}
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}

{# And make sure to only output the links if the element exists #}
{% if prevEntry %}<a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">Previous</a>{% endif %}
{% if nextEntry %}<a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">Next</a>{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that the `entry` already set for the URL I'm viewing would know about what came before and after.

Comment: For anyone in the same position has me who has a few entries with identical post dates (both date and time are the same), for this to work properly if ordering by post date, you also need to specify the secondary sort parameter Craft uses, which, from a quick inspect of the entries section of the CMS seems to be id (ascending). So the full criteria would be `craft.entries.section(mySection).order('postDate desc, id asc')`.

Comment: How do I get this to work in Craft 3? I can get the prev & next urls via the paginate tag but I'm stuck on how to retrieve the entry titles...

Answer (score 20):

You can set the `prev.url` at the top of the template, for example:

```
{% set criteria = {section: 'blog', order: 'postDate'} %}
{% set prev = entry.getPrev(criteria) %}
```

Add a link if `prev` is available:

```
{% if prev %}
   <a href="{{ prev.url }}">{{ prev.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry @Patrick, didn't see you edited your answer before I composed mine. Now pretty much identical.

Answer (score 3):

For navigating siblings in a `structure` there's a shortcut:

```twig
{% if entry.prevSibling %}<a href="{{ entry.prevSibling.url }}">Previous</a>{% endif %}
{% if entry.nextSibling %}<a href="{{ entry.nextSibling.url }}">Next</a>{% endif %}
```