# How can I show next/previous paging that's limited by specific criteria?

Tags: pagination, previous-next

I'm adding prev/next links to a detail page and can't get `craft.entries` to return the correct entries.

**Specifically, I need `craft.entries` to return entries in the "leadership" section where the `leadershipType` field matches the current entry's `leadershipType` value.**

My code returns all entries instead of the ones specific to my field parameter.

```
{% set params = craft.entries.section('leadership').find({ leadershipType:entry.leadershipType }) %}

{% set prev = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set next= entry.getNext(params) %}?

{% if prev %}<a href="{{ prev.url }}">&lt;</a>{% endif %}
{% if next %}<a href="{{ next.url }}">&gt;</a>{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry for that stupid edit I made yesterday, Anna! Must have been very confused with something.

Comment: No problem. Probably my field name using "type" is confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only pass [**an object**](https://github.com/brandonkelly/TwigForDesigners/blob/master/values-expressions-and-variables.md#objects) or an ElementCriteriaModel (what you get when you type 'craft.entries') into `getNext()` and `getPrev()`.

Calling `find()` on an ElementCriteriaModel, as I'm doing in my code, turns it into an actual array of entries, which is not something `getNext()` and `getPrev()` can work with.

So changing the first line to this will work:

```
{% set params = craft.entries.section('leadership').leadershipType(entry.leadershipType) %}
```

Or this using the object syntax for setting parameters:

```
{% set params = craft.entries({
    section: 'leadership',
    leadershipType: entry.leadershipType
}) %}
```

Comment: we had [exactly the same question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-to-link-to-previous-next-entries-in-a-section) this morning already :)

Comment: I saw that when posting. My question adds the need to limit by a specific field which is why I posted a new question.