# Get next entry based on entry type

Tags: templating, entry, entry-type

As an extension of this question
[How to link to previous/next entries in a section?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-to-link-to-previous-next-entries-in-a-section)

If my page is set to automatically provide a `entry` var in my template.
And I can simply access a field like this

```
entry.title
```

Which means I don't need to do something like this

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('blog').first() %}
```

If I want to get the next entry and previous entry based on this entry's entry type. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you still have to set the parameters by your own:

```
{# Get this entry's entry type #}
{% set type = entry.getType() %}

{# Set parameters for prev/next elements list #}
{% set params = craft.entries.section('blog').type(type) %}

{# Get the prev/next elements #}
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}

{# And make sure to only output the links if the element exists #}
{% if prevEntry %}<a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">Previous</a>{% endif %}
{% if nextEntry %}<a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">Next</a>{% endif %}
```