# Entries order postDate not working

Tags: entries, ordering, previous-next

I'm trying to get prev/next entry using positionedAfter and positionedBefore filters but getting weird order on results because order('postDate desc') seems to be ignored.

```
{% set prevSibling = craft.entries.positionedAfter(entry).order('postDate desc').first() %}

{% set nextSibling = craft.entries.positionedBefore(entry).order('postDate desc').first() %}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

`positionedAfter` only applies to entries within a structure section (https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#positionedAfter). See [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/58/642) for how to get next and previous entries.

Comment: Thanks that answer helped, but I still see problem in craft core because I am using structure and order is wrong for positionedAfter and positionedBefore

Comment: `positionedAfter` and `positionedBefore` will return the entry before/after in the Structure in the CMS, regardless of how you order them on the front end using `.order()`. If you're using this for a blog, you should be using a channel rather than a structure.